# How do I get the current absolute URL in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url

How can I get the current **absolute** URL in my Ruby on Rails view?

The `request.request_uri` only returns the **relative** URL.

Comment: You can have a look for rails 4: http://blog.grepruby.com/2015/04/absolute-url-full-url-in-rails-4.html

Answer (score 1508, accepted):

#### For Rails 3.2 or Rails 4+

You should use `request.original_url` to get the current URL.  Source code on current repo found [here](https://pix.realquadrant.com/original_url).

This method is documented at [original_url method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-original_url), but if you're curious, the implementation is:

```
def original_url
  base_url + original_fullpath
end
```

---

#### For Rails 3:

You can write `"#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{request.fullpath}"`, since `request.url` is now deprecated.

---

#### For Rails 2:

You  can write `request.url` instead of `request.request_uri`.  This combines the protocol (usually http://) with the host, and request_uri to give you the full address.

Comment: as other users pointed:
DEPRECATION WARNING: Using #request_uri is deprecated. Use fullpath instead

Comment: @giladbu `fullpath` does NOT include the protocol/domain/port! It’s not an absolute URL!

Comment: `"http://#{request.host+request.fullpath}"` will work or otherwise, (if the port is important) `"http://#{request.host}:#{request.port+request.fullpath}"`

Comment: if port important, this one works right: 

`"http://#{request.host}:#{request.port}#{request.fullpath}"`

Comment: You can also use `request.host_with_port` to make something compatible with both production and dev envs.

Comment: Its clear that the `request.*` api has changed a lot between rails versions and may continue to change. However, the api for `url_for` has remained mostly constant. I would use `url_for` for that reason. I woud say that @grzuy's answer is the best one.

Comment: Can you point to a reference for the claim that `request.url` is deprecated? The proposed solution is just a long way of saying what `request.url` already does; the implementation is simply protocol + host_with_port + fullpath (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/33841a9db3e560ef062d36d14ea07f7d71dd65ab/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/url.rb#L86)

Comment: This answer is outdated! See @Mike's answer for a smarter solution (i.e. use `request.original_url`).

Comment: how do you use this with `link_to request.original_url` and add an extra parameter? somehow with `params.merge` maybe?

Comment: What if there is no `request` because I am not in controller but in a worker thread?

Answer (score 141):

I think that the Ruby on Rails 3.0 method is now `request.fullpath`.

Comment: fullpath doesn't include the domain

Comment: I'm glad this was provided as I was actually searching for how to not include the domain.

Answer (score 130):

You could use `url_for(only_path: false)`

Comment: In my (a bit special case) this was almost exactly what I wanted. I just changed the option to true and got the url for the current page, without options. Thanks :)

Comment: @David not in the View it doesn't. But it should'n be used there anyway =)

Comment: In my case I wanted to change host name but keep everything else. I found that url_for(host: 'www.newdomain.com') worked the best for me as a solution to the problem. IMO, its a more robust solution since its the same across all versions of rails.

Comment: FYI This will not work if you have multiple paths for the same resource.

Comment: For a `/activities/:id` path I got `404?id=:id` when doing `url_for(only_path: false)` from a page handling "not found", `request.original_url` works fine

Answer (score 68):

If you're using **Rails 3.2** or **Rails 4**, you should use `request.original_url` to get the current URL.

---

Documentation for the method is at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-original_url, but if you're curious, the implementation is:

```
def original_url
  base_url + original_fullpath
end
```

**EDIT**: This is still the case for **Rails 7** ([Docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-original_url)).

Answer (score 67):

DEPRECATION WARNING: [Using #request_uri is deprecated](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Http/URL/request_uri). Use fullpath instead.

Comment: See notes on answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2165727/166279, fullpath doesn't include the domain.

Comment: this line came straight from the log at time of writing when using `request.uri` and this has already been pointed out several times in this question, but... ok, thanks

Comment: @ManishShrivastava: funny, in spite of all the "original" effort I put answering more complex questions, this copy and paste gave me the highest score, well... better than nothing

Answer (score 52):

You can add this [current_url](http://grosser.it/2008/11/06/current_url) method in the ApplicationController to return the current URL and allow merging in other parameters

```
# https://x.com/y/1?page=1 
# + current_url( :page => 3 )
# = https://x.com/y/1?page=3
def current_url(overwrite={})
    url_for :only_path => false, :params => params.merge(overwrite)
end
```

**Example Usage:**

```
current_url --> http://...
current_url(:page=>4) --> http://...&page=4
```

Comment: This does not appear to be defined in Rails 3.1.

Comment: you could do it this way `url_for params.merge(:format => "PDF", :only_path => false)`

Comment: also if you are in a `link_to` you can just use `params.merge` and skip the `url_for` altogether

Answer (score 39):

For Ruby on Rails 3:

```
request.url
request.host_with_port
```

I fired up a debugger session and queried the request object:

```
request.public_methods
```

Answer (score 32):

In Ruby on Rails 3.1.0.rc4:

```
 request.fullpath
```

Comment: `fullpath` does not provide an `absolute URL` as the original poster requested.

Answer (score 29):

I needed the application [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) but with the subdirectory. I used:

```
root_url(:only_path => false)
```

Answer (score 28):

```
 url_for(params)
```

And you can easily add some new parameter:

```
url_for(params.merge(:tag => "lol"))
```

Comment: This is far more elegant (if less granular) than the approved answer.

Answer (score 16):

I think request.domain would work, but what if you're in a sub directory like blah.blah.com? Something like this could work:

```
<%= request.env["HTTP_HOST"] + page = "/" + request.path_parameters['controller'] + "/" + request.path_parameters['action'] %>
```

Change the parameters based on your path structure.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes Jaime's answer is way better, but if you want to be really inefficient, you could do it my way.

Answer (score 14):

It looks like `request_uri` is deprecated in Ruby on Rails 3.

```
Using #request_uri is deprecated. Use fullpath instead.
```

Answer (score 13):

Using Ruby 1.9.3-p194 and Ruby on Rails 3.2.6:

If **request.fullpath** doesn't work for you, try **request.env["HTTP_REFERER"]**

Here's my story below.

I got similar problem with detecting current URL (which is shown in address bar for user in her browser) for cumulative pages which combines information from different controllers, for example, `http://localhost:3002/users/1/history/issues`.

The user can switch to different lists of types of issues. All those lists are loaded via Ajax from different controllers/partials (without reloading).

The problem was to set the correct path for the back button in each item of the list so the back button could work correctly both in its own page and in the cumulative page *history*.

In case I use **request.fullpath**, it returns the path of last JavaScript request which is definitely not the URL I'm looking for.

So I used **request.env["HTTP_REFERER"]** which stores the URL of the last reloaded request.

Here's an excerpt from the partial to make a decision

```
- if request.env["HTTP_REFERER"].to_s.scan("history").length > 0
  - back_url = user_history_issue_path(@user, list: "needed_type")
- else
  - back_url = user_needed_type_issue_path(@user)
- remote ||= false
=link_to t("static.back"), back_url, :remote => remote
```

Comment: Yup, fullpath gets you the url you requested, not the url you *came from*, which is what I needed as well. Thanks for this!

Comment: Works great, just what I needed. This should be in a seperate question and answer though. Kinda hard to find here. :/

Answer (score 12):

This works for Ruby on Rails 3.0 and should be supported by most versions of Ruby on Rails:

```
request.env['REQUEST_URI']
```

Answer (score 12):

None of the suggestions here in the thread helped me sadly, except the one where someone said he used the debugger to find what he looked for.

I've created some custom error pages instead of the standard 404 and 500, but `request.url` ended in `/404` instead of the expected `/non-existing-mumbo-jumbo`.

What I needed to use was

```
request.original_url
```

Answer (score 9):

If by relative, you mean just without the domain, then look into `request.domain`.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the ruby method:

```
:root_url
```

which will get the full path with base url:

```
localhost:3000/bla
```

Comment: This is the only solution that works in serializers using active_model_serializers in Rails 4.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I restrict the params I pass to an absolute url when I use somethin like `:root_url` to get the absolute url ? Assume I'm usin somethin like `some_method(:products_brand_url, brand: brand, entity_name: "brand")` and `some_method` is defined as
`
def some_method(route, opts = {})
end
`
I don't want my route to look like - `http://localhost:3000/brands/brand_name?&entity_name="brand"`. I want the route to look like `http://localhost:3000/brands/brand_name`. I just want the `entity_name` to be a part of the opts hash and not as a params to the absolute url.

Comment: Certainly there's no _Ruby_ method called `root_url`.

Answer (score 8):

```
(url_for(:only_path => false) == "/" )? root_url : url_for(:only_path => false)
```

Answer (score 6):

In Rails 3 you can use

```
request.original_url
```

http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActionDispatch/Request/original_url

Answer (score 6):

you can use any one for rails 3.2:

```
request.original_url
or
request.env["HTTP_REFERER"]
or
request.env['REQUEST_URI']
```

I think it will work every where

```
"#{request.protocol}#{request.host}:#{request.port}#{request.fullpath}"
```

Answer (score 6):

**Rails 4.0**

you can use `request.original_url`, output will be as given below example

```
get "/articles?page=2"

request.original_url # => "http://www.example.com/articles?page=2"
```

Answer (score 5):

You can either use

```
request.original_url
```

or

```
"#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}"
```

to get the current URL.

Answer (score 5):

**For Rails 3.2 or Rails 4**
Simply get in this way "request.original_url"
Reference: [Original URL Method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-original_url)

**For Rails 3**
As request.url is deprecated.We can get absolute path by concatenating

```
"#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{request.fullpath}"
```

**For Rails 2**

```
request.url
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want to be specific, meaning, you know the path you need:

```
link_to current_path(@resource, :only_path => false), current_path(@resource)
```

Answer (score 3):

For rails 3 :

> request.fullpath

Answer (score 3):

```
request.env["REQUEST_URI"]
```

works in rails 2.3.4 tested and do not know about other versions.

Answer (score 3):

To get the request URL without any query parameters.

```
def current_url_without_parameters
  request.base_url + request.path
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set a variable to `URI.parse(current_url)`, I don't see this proposal here yet and it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
request.full_path
```

or

```
request.url
```

Hopefully it will resolve your problem.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

For Rails 3.x and up:

```
#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{request.fullpath}
```

For Rails 3.2 and up:

```
request.original_url
```

Because in rails 3.2 and up:

```
request.original_url = request.base_url + request.original_fullpath
```

For more info, plese visit http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-original_url

Answer (score 0):

To get the absolute URL which means that the `from the root` it can be displayed like this

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_url(user) %>
```

The users_url helper generates a URL that includes the protocol and host 
name.  The users_path helper generates only the path portion.

```
users_url: http://localhost/users
users_path: /users
```

Answer (score 0):

**Rails 4**

Controller:

```
def absolute_url
  request.base_url + request.original_fullpath
end
```

**Action Mailer Notable changes in [4.2 release](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html):**

link_to and url_for generate absolute URLs by default in templates, it is no longer needed to pass only_path: false. (Commit)

View:

If you use the `_url` suffix, the generated URL is absolute. Use `_path` to get a relative URL.

```
<%= link_to "Home", root_url %>
```

For More Details, go to:

http://blog.grepruby.com/2015/04/absolute-url-full-url-in-rails-4.html

Comment: A custom method is not needed.  The correct answer is above.

Answer (score -2):

you can get absolute url by calling:

```
request.original_url
```

or

```
request.env['HTTP_REFERER']
```