# Rails - restrict URL access to images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a Rails app and using the restful-authentication plugin. The app will include user images. Only users who log in will be able to browse, but I wondered if I can also restrict direct URL access to the images to only allow logged-in users.

In other words, even if you know that an image is at `thesite.com/user1/foo.jpg`, you can't see that image unless you're logged in. I know this could theoretically be done in the Apache config, but the only way I know would involve manual editing of those files, which wouldn't scale.

Is this possible? Would it make more sense to just move the photos out of the `public` directory? (I'm not sure if that has any performance implications, as `public` is generally used for static content.)

Comment: You'd have to send the images throw the controller like 
David Antaramian said, which, depending on your userbase, could be a performance bottleneck. May want to try to do the image filtering higher up at rack layer (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html) or even higher up.

Comment: @clyfe - why might this be a performance bottleneck? Because rails has to get involved with processing the binary data instead of just letting Apache handle it?

Comment: Yes, Apache will be faster than ruby/Rails.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a controller action for images that just returns the binary data to the user (from a source not publicly accessible) only if the user is logged in. As a preface to this, I'm a Django/Python person, not Ruby/Rails, but from what I can tell, the configuration would look like this:

```
map.connect ':user/:picture', :controller => 'accounts', :action => 'displayPic'
```

and your actual controller would look something like:

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
    def image
        # check if user is logged in, then
        user = Account.find(params[:user])
        image = get_image(user, params[:picture])
        send_data(image,
             :filename => "#{params[:picture]}",
             :type => "image/jpeg")
    end

private

    def get_image(image_name)
        # do something to find image
        # and return the binary data
        # to the action
    end
end
```

Made this a community wiki so anyone with better Ruby/Rails skills can clean it up

Answer (score 2):

Just require a user for the action:

```
# images_controller.rb
ImagesController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :require_user, :only => 'show'

  def require_user
    unless current_user
      redirect_to root_url # or :back, or wherever
    end
  end

end
```

However, do you really mean direct access to the image not via `http://yoursite.com/userfoo/bar.jpg`, but via `http://yoursite.com/images/system/file/5837/bar.jpg`? Within rails, you could check the request object:

```
# images_controller.rb
ImagesController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :require_onsite, :only => 'show'

  def require_onsite
    # pseudoruby, might need some massage
    unless request.referer.match(/request.domain/) 
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: If the URL is http://yoursite.com/images/system/file/5837/bar.jpg you are saying to check the request object. Does this work in Ruby on Rails 3? I couldn't find a reference. Thanks

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165665/how-do-i-get-the-current-url-in-ruby-on-rails