# How can I Get the RAW URL from a request in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble debugging a client, and I'm trying to get the raw URL on the server which is in rails.  I'm wondering how I can dump the raw URL/http message that is hitting rails.

If found query_string, which works okay for gets. But if a user does a post, I can't seem to find the raw string anywhere.

All I can find is post-parsed parameters in hashes vs raw URLs.

Help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
request.url
```

Will give the current url.

See other answers:

[How do I get the current absolute URL in Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165665/how-to-get-current-url-in-rails)

Comment: This doesn't actually return the raw URL. For example, if there's a trailing / on the original request, it'll be missing. `request.env['REQUEST_PATH']` is a less altered path, though it doesn't include the host.