# How to get request's target controller and action with Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In the application controller before filter.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :authenticate

  def authenticate
    # How do we know which controller and action was targetted?
  end
end
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165665/how-do-i-get-the-current-url-in-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 87, accepted):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :authenticate

  def authenticate
    # How do we know which controller and action was targetted?
    params[:controller]
    params[:action]
    # OR
    controller.controller_name
    controller.action_name    
  end
end
```

Comment: <irony>I have got ready file with bunch of answers for standart questions :)</irony>

Comment: We used to use `params[:action]` just fine. But for some reason in the last month or so this stopped working. Now it comes up as an empty hash. However, `controller.action_name` continues to work. We're on Rails 3.2. Not sure why it stopped working, but I would suggest using `controller.action_name` as it seems more reliable.

Answer (score 16):

In Rails 3.2 you no longer need to call controller.action_name explicitly instead just "action_name".

```
before_filter :check_if_locked


def check_if_locked
  puts action_name
  puts controller_name
end
```

Comment: I like this better than the params reference because it strips the path prefix off and just gives the controller name.

Answer (score 13):

You can get full url object using

`url = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(request.env['PATH_INFO'])`

now you can get components as

`url[:controller]`

`url[:action]`

By default you can also use `params[:controller]` and `params[:action]` respectively during request/response life cycle.

Comment: Handy outside request / response cycle, but absolutely un-necessary during it.

Comment: This code is really handy to parse a url stored in some string variable.

Comment: Edited the answer for way to use within request/response cycle.

Comment: This will only work for requests of HTTP GET method. To support all methods, use `url = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(request.env['PATH_INFO'], { :method => request.env['REQUEST_METHOD'] })`.

Answer (score 5):

```
request.parameters['controller']
request.parameters['action']
```