# Rails request with id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to detect the ID in which my page is called.

Example: 
`http://localhost:3000#technical-options`

the browser jumps to the element with id `technical-options` but i am not able to detect the full request by ruby / rails.

this did not help
[How do I get the current absolute URL in Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165665/how-do-i-get-the-current-absolute-url-in-ruby-on-rails)

`request.url`, `request.fullpath` are not delivering the id after the `#`

many thanks

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418454/how-to-get-requests-target-controller-and-action-with-rails-3) should help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible from chrome since chrome doesn't send the parameter after the hash in the request.

Comment: @Gautam: didn't work - all of theese options. My workaround ist to generate a url like: `http://localhost:3000/?id=radio-free#radio-free`. its no problem, because the url is created by script, but not nice, but might be the only way to navigate to the ID and have the information in the controller