# In Rails, how to get current URL (but no paths)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

If I'm in a URL such as

```
http://domain.example/mysite/bla
```

How can I request just the URL with no paths? Such as

```
http://domain.example
```

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165665/how-to-get-current-url-in-rails

Comment: It's not a duplicate, because author wants to return only protocol with host but not full url

Comment: You should accept @fl00r's answer, it's the best one.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You can use this

```
<%= request.protocol + request.host_with_port %>
#=> https://domain.example:3000
<%= request.protocol + request.host %>
#=> https://domain.example
```

Starting from Rails 3.2 you can also use

```
<%= request.base_url %>
#=> https://domain.example:3000
```

Comment: Just to complement If you need more info check https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/URL.html

Answer (score 5):

`request.host` should do the trick, or:

```
request.port.blank? ? request.host : "#{request.host}: #{request.port}"
```

if you need to include the port too.

Comment: that doesn't include the port if specified

Comment: `request.port.blank? ? request.host : "#{request.host}: #{request.port}"`

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
<%=request.scheme + '://' + request.host_with_port%>
```

If you want to see all available methods on request object then

```
<%=request.methods.sort%>
```

Answer (score 2):

For protocol, domain and port

```
<%= "#{request.protocol + request.host}:#{request.port.to_s}" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can get your current domain name.

Domain name

```rb
request.base_url 
# prod: https://example.com
# dev: https://localhost:8000
```

Getting full path

```rb
request.original_url
# prod: https://example.com/path/
# dev: https://localhost:8000/path/
```

Answer (score 0):

If your port could be anything other than 80 it should be included.

```
"#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be useful too, if you're not in a controller.

```
URI.join(url_for(only_path: false), '/').to_s
```