# Rails 3 get request referrer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using Rails 3.0.9, Ruby 1.9.2, Devise 1.3.4 and has a need in Devise session new view to access the request url parameters although I see this as a general Rails request handling question. Essentially, a request is made to a Devise authenticated resource which redirects the user to the login screen. In the login view, I need access to the request url, eg, this is the request url called in the beginning

```
http://mysite.com/article/5?type=blah
```

In the redirect login page, I need access to that URL, anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use `request.referer` or `request.env['HTTP_REFERER']` in your controller to get the referer url.

Comment: Tried that, didn't work, it shows the login screen url. By that, I meant in the sessions controller. If I put the code in `articles` controller, it wouldn't get executed until after the login is authenticated.

Comment: If I understand your requirements right, you want to redirect the user to the page, where he was before the login action. Why don't you simply save the redirect url in the session, when the user clicks login?

Comment: The redirection to the login page is already handled properly, what I need is on the login page asking for the user creds, I need access to the original request url, hope that makes more sense. I should clarify that the original call comes from another server, not a browser.

Comment: I think you just have to save the referer before you redirect the user to the login page. And when the user successfully logs in redirect him to the stored value.

Comment: Yeah it didn't work but found a workaround specific to Devise, thanks for your effort though.

Comment: Hey Johnny, can you please share with us the workaround that you found ? I have the same thing here .. thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165665/how-do-i-get-the-current-url-in-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 3):

I have just found out that WEBrick handles **request.referrer** incorrectly. But don't worry. Unicorn handles it right.
I did't test that on other servers. You should check this with yours. I don't think that you use WEBrick as a production server.

Comment: Indeed WEBrick is not appropriate for a production server. I also found differences in how WEBrick and Puma handled `request.referrer` - definitely worth checking if `request.referrer` doesn't behave as expected using WEBrick.