# Ruby on rails, getting the URL that initiate this controller's action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Inside my controller, I want to know how can I get the URL that calls my controller?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers

Comment: and possible duplicate with [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165665/how-do-i-get-the-current-url-in-ruby-on-rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165665/how-do-i-get-the-current-url-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: @jbh that question is about the current URL, I am asking for the calling URL

Comment: @SteveNg You mean the referrer ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8071913/rails-3-get-request-referrer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
request.env['HTTP_REFERER']
```

or

```
request.referer
```