# Where do I find info about everything I can log from a visitor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, httprequest

I want to collect info about the visitor - like IP-number, referer, agent etc. I assume this is possible with Ruby on Rails (e.g. `request.referer`), but I cannot find the documentation for this.

**Is there any documentation that lists everything that I can log about visits to my app?**

Comment: Headers partially depend on what user browser send to the server, intermediary servers, etc. Can you be more specific about what ou expect?

Comment: I'm looking for the info from user that you traditionally collect in analytics software.

Comment: So all you can get is in `request.headers`, try it out in development, this hash includes all headers received by server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-headers) what you're looking for?

**EDIT**:

So, yeah, in the above link you get some methods for accessing the headers.

You can also access the referrer using the method you said, or with `request.env['HTTP_REFERER']`. Some more information here:

[Rails 3 get request referrer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8071913/rails-3-get-request-referrer)

[How to get request referer path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819721/how-to-get-request-referrer-path)

As for the agent, I made a little research, since I never used, and it seems you can access it with `request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`. It seems there's also a [gem](https://github.com/josh/useragent) avaliable for the task.

Please let me know if these work out for you =]

Comment: Yes! :) But is there any more? Like `agent` and `referer`?

Comment: Link only answers are not cool, please at least copy some docs you link to over here!

Comment: @Fellow  request.env.keys