# Rails how to request url except url params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am creating this link tag:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="<%= request.url %>" />
```

The problem is just it is the full url with params.

How do I request the url without any params?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`request.url.split('?').first`

Answer (score 11):

`request` is an ActionDispatch::Request and that subclasses Rack::Request. Rack::Request has a `path` method that might interest you:

```
<%= request.path %>
```

If your `request.url` is `http://example.com/where/is?pancakes=house%3F` then `request.path` should be `/where/is`.

Comment: I think James´ solution is the best choice in my case, because I need the full url, not just only the path.

Comment: @Victor: Can you be a little more explicit about what "does not work" means?

Comment: Sure. `request.path` gives me the path and the parameters after `?`. `request.url.split('?').first` worked as expected.

Comment: @Victor: `request.path` isn't including the query string for me in 3.2 so I'm not sure what's up with your code. What sort of route are you using?

Comment: Well, I already solved the problem in my codebase. I'm working on other things now. Thanks for comments/answers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165665/how-do-i-get-the-current-url-in-ruby-on-rails