# Autofill form based on URL string value in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a website with a form for location on the front page. I want to auto-populate the form with values based on a URL string. How can I do this in rails?

For example, I would like the form to show with the value New York when the user arrives on the front page based on something like: website.com?city="New York"

How best to implement this in rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can get the current request url, everything is here : [How do I get the current absolute URL in Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165665/how-do-i-get-the-current-url-in-ruby-on-rails)

Then you just have to "parse" it :

```
<% city = request.fullpath.split('=').last %>
```

Will return "New York" with a url like `website.com?city="New York"`
(Not sure about this one but maybe you can get it only with params[:city], I just don't think `params` is available in a view)

The rest depends on the structure of your form...