# Rails 3: redirect_to specifying host doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, subdomain

I want to redirect the user to a named route but to a different subdomain. I thought that specifying the host as the last param to `redirect_to` would do it, but it just doesn't work. Here is the code I am using:

```
redirect_to(log_in_url(return_to: request.fullpath), host: "https://acme.lvh.me:3000/")
```

For some reason that doesn't work. Here is a scenario and what's happening:

- I'm on `https://oauth.lvh.me:3000/oauth/authorize`
- I use the `redirect_to` method specified above.
- It redirects me to `https://oauth.lvh.me:3000/log_in`
- It should instead have redirected me to `https://acme.lvh.me:3000/log_in`

What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem myself. First of all the `host: "https://acme.lvh.me:3000/` should be `host: acme.lvh.me` instead. Second of all, the option should be passed to the `log_in_url` method not to the `return_to` method!

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be simple. Try with something like this:

```
redirect_to request.url.sub('oauth', 'acme')
```

Comment: I found the solution to my problem, look at my answer. By the way, `request.url` is deprecated, use `"#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{request.fullpath}"` instead for a similar output. Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165665/how-do-i-get-the-current-url-in-ruby-on-rails