# Is there a way to get client's actual port in a rails web application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache2

I want to get client's actual port number(*the port that router gave to client computer*) in a rails web application.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for something like `request.remote_port` since there is `request.remote_ip`

This is what I came up with `request.env["REMOTE_PORT"]`

Comment: That didn't work for me. There's no env["REMOTE_PORT"] variable.

Comment: But there is `request.env["REMOTE_PORT"]`. I've amended the answer.

Comment: I tried to check for request.env["REMOTE_PORT"] and it's not there (at least for Rails 4.2)

Answer (score 1):

At least in Rails 5.2+, request.env["REMOTE_PORT"] is blank, so I downvoted the other answer.

After some digging, the way I managed to obtain this information was setting a custom header in nginx.

You probably have something like this in your nginx configuration:

```
upstream {{ param_app_name }} {
  server unix:///var/www/{{ param_app_name }}/shared/tmp/sockets/puma-{{ param_app_name }}.sock;
}

...


location / {
    try_files $uri @app;
  }

  location @app {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Client-Request-Port $remote_port; # << -- Add this to your nginx conf
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://{{ param_app_name }};
  }
```

As you can see, you can pass custom headers from nginx to your Rails backend, using `proxy_set_header` in the same server block you are using proxy_pass to invoke your backend.

The header name `X-Client-Request-Port` is arbitrary and you can choose whatever you like, but there's an old convention to use `X-...` for custom headers.

After setting this up and reloading your nginx, you can access this value in Rails simply by using `request.headers["X-Client-Request-Port"]`.

By the way, I assume you are asking this for logging purposes. If that's the case, I suggest you take a look at Lograge gem, which will make your log entries a single line per request only, reducing the mess that Rails default logger is in production. I have it configured like this following Ankane's guide [here](https://github.com/ankane/production_rails#logging):

```
In ApplicationController:

def append_info_to_payload(payload)
    super

    payload[:remote_ip] = request.remote_ip
    payload[:remote_port] = request.headers["X-Client-Request-Port"]
    payload[:user_id] = current_user.id     if current_user
    # You can add more custom stuff here, just whitelist it in production.rb below.
  end

Then, in config/environments/production.rb:

config.lograge.enabled = true

  config.lograge.custom_options = lambda do |event|
    options = event.payload.slice(
      :request_id,
      :user_id,
      :remote_ip,
      :remote_port,
    )
    options[:params] = event.payload[:params].except("controller", "action")
    options
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this question and answers:

[How do I get the current absolute URL in Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165665/how-do-i-get-the-current-url-in-ruby-on-rails)

This should be the trick:

```
"#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{request.fullpath}"
"#{request.protocol}#{request.host}:#{request.port+request.fullpath}"
```

Comment: well what I am looking for is remote port. which is client' port number. not my own server port number.

Answer (score 0):

On rails 6.1  works: `request.headers['REMOTE_PORT']`
Using using nginx + passenger