# Get the value of one word dynamically in rails static page cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have static pages in my app. This app is running on two different domains.

I want some of the static pages to show <%=@domain%> name. All the contents are static but only the domain name is dynamic. How can I get this done in rails?

like

```
cache do
 some content goes here and then i want to display the <%=request.domain()%>
end
```

With the above way: request.domain() will cached first and will be served with the same domain name ignoring which domain you are using to access this later.

Comment: [Maybe this question will be of help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165665/how-do-i-get-the-current-url-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: no man. this is not to get the current URL. say if i get the current url and gets this url cached first time, it will be same url for all users visiting the site. 

its about caching + dynamic host name

Comment: By static you mean this is in `public/` dir?

Comment: Why don't you generate the file on deploy / startup? I mean the domain will not change during runtime. Either do it in your capistrano deploy.rb or add an initializer that generates the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well. I found a solution which seems simple and easy. I added a key to caching and that will create two different keys for each domain and when a user will visit a domain on the basis of key it will pick up the cached contents. Thanks all for your feedback.

```
 cache("#{@page_title}_#{request.domain()}") 
   some static text goes here <%=request.domain()%> 
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

in your view:

```
<%= request.domain() %>
```

on my local machine app that runs on `localhost:3000` the above code returns `localhost` on the screen.

```
cache "first_part_up_to_domain_name" do
 some content goes here and then i want to display the 
end

<%=request.domain()%>

cache "the_rest_after_domain_name" do
 rest of the content
end
```

in other cases with dynamic pages you could use expire cache method to overwrite the cached pages, but with static pages not sure how you can do this.

Comment: may be I've not explained it well. let me explain it again
'cache do
 some static content goes here and i also want to display <%=request.domain()%>
end'

with the above way: request.domain() will cached first and will be served with the same domain name ignoring which domain you are using to access this

Comment: may be :) I understood that you want the domain name to appear on your page.

Comment: i just modified the question to help better understanding.

Comment: do you cache all the pages? where do you show the domain name? may be you better cache your content up to the domain name, and start another cache frame after the domain name so the `<%= request.domain %>` stays out of cache

Comment: well. I found a solution which seems simple and easy. I added a key to caching and that will create two different keys for each domain and when a user will visit a domain on the basis of key it will pick up the cached contents. Thanks all for your feedback. 

    cache("#{@page_title}_#{request.domain()}")
      some static text goes here <%=request.domain()%>
    end