# Rails way to put localhost in include tags and javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, faye

I've set up a rails app with faye.

It includes the following code parts:

*applications.html.haml:*

```
= javascript_include_tag "http://localhost:9292/faye.js"
```

*discussions.js:*

```
$(function() {
  var faye = new Faye.Client('http://localhost:9292/faye');
  faye.subscribe("/messages/new", function(data) {
    eval(data);
  });
});
```

When I run the app on localhost in dev mode everything works fine.
On the VPS server, it tries to reach my "localhost:9292/faye", when it should be the servers localhost.

Q: Is there a method, or way to get it working with the same code on both the server and localhost? Manually changing to the domain isn't looks the rails way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use:

```
"#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}/faye"
```

for more info:

[How do I get the current absolute URL in Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165665/how-do-i-get-the-current-url-in-ruby-on-rails/17426958#answer-17426958)