# request.original_url in Fb-comments Div

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, facebook

I'm trying to include Facebook Comments in my app (Rails4).

The Div for the comments is

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="{URL_HERE}" data-width="570"></div>
```

where {URL_HERE} i need

```
request.original_url
```

or the url of the current page.

How can i set this up ?

I tried

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="#{request.original_url}" data-width="570"></div>
```

But i'm getting a error from facebook

[image]

Comment: You can do `data-href="#{request.original_url}"`

Comment: Good morning bro :), tried that already :( (I Updated my Question)

Comment: look the error `<iframe name= iframe_a/> <a href="#{request.original_url}" target="iframe_a">Facebook</a> ` did you try this

Comment: I entered the interpolation in the href field. This plugin does not have an iframe implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, i got it. Didn't need to use interpolation here.

```
<%= request.original_url %>
```

For anyone who stumbles upon this:

For **Rails 3.2** or **Rails 4** you should use `request.original_url` to get the current URL. [More detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165665/how-do-i-get-the-current-url-in-ruby-on-rails/17426958#answer-17426958).

**For Rails 3:** You want `"#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{request.fullpath}"`, since `request.url` is now deprecated.

**For Rails 2:** You want `request.url` instead of `request.request_uri`. This combines the protocol (usually http://) with the host, and request_uri to give you the full address.

Comment: can you please help me am also facing same problem.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22879718/ruby-on-rails-how-to-get-current-page-url/22879734?noredirect=1#