# How to get current page URL?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook

I am adding fb shared button in application using the docs at [Share Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button). Its working fine, but I want to share the current page's URL in facebook. For example:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-type="button"></div>
```

I want to fill my current URL `href` section, how can i achieve this

```
http://localhost:3000/news/view/2
```

This is my URL, here id changing each time, instead of `developers.facebook.com` how can I add my URL id here.

Answer (score 3):

```
request.original_url
```

will return current url. refere this [link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-original_url) for more info.

Comment: @priyank patel and alok anandh, i want to current news article page in facebook in application..how can i change my code there in href section

Comment: @Ullas you mean to say that you want something like href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/2"

Comment: ,yes i am running in local host my news application, i want to share this news,news are in differnt id eg: http://localhost:3000/news/view/2

Comment: @XYZ_deve [Answered below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22879886/1376448). Does that help?

Comment: @XYZ_deve ok, if you want href like this href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/2", do this href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/ + #{params[:page or article whatever it denotes 2]}"

Comment: @Alok thanks, i mean page not like that,i want to share my current article (news) page in fb..for that wat i have to do.

Comment: @XYZ_deve  "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u="+request.original_url or "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u="+request.fullpath....

Comment: @AlokAnand my question similar to this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18458635/request-original-url-in-fb-comments-div                                                        but am not getting result, can you please help me

Answer (score 2):

Rails > 3.2 `request.original_url`

Rails 2: `request.url`

Found SO Questions you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18458635/request-original-url-in-fb-comments-div) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165665/how-do-i-get-the-current-absolute-url-in-ruby-on-rails) :) .

Answer (score 2):

Use `request.original_url` and change that code as:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<%= request.original_url %>" data-type="button"></div>
```

As per [Share Button Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button), `data-href` parameter contains the `URL` which one wants to share, above will just do the same.

`<%= %>` embeds and evaluates Ruby code inside your template. So, it will enable you to share your current page using FB share.

Hope that helps

Comment: Even the other link you specified uses same method; I see no reason why it shouldn't work. Can you update the question with the markup generated after u made the above change?

Comment: Its coming facebook share page,inside full of empty..there is no error showing..i want to share my current news ,which contain differnt id..

Comment: @XYZ_deve It's little hard to decipher what you want to convey with that. Can you update your question with the screenshot of the screen and pastebin the complete HTML markup of that corresponding page? It may help us :)

Comment: can i get your any kind of chat id,can you please help me to solve this problem