# How to pass value from js to html.erb render function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, erb

I have a partial to which I have to send a parameter -> update_path, which I get from javascript function window.location.href, is there a way I can do it? e.g.
`<%= render('abc', :update_path => 'path') %>`

Can I set the update_path value of render partial parameters?

Comment: The syntax would be `render(:partial =>'abc', :locals => { update_path => 'path' })`

Comment: not clear, could you please add more information?

Comment: @MrYoshiji His syntax actually works fine. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/RenderingHelper.html#method-i-render - "If no options hash is passed or :update specified, the default is to render a partial and use the second parameter as the locals hash"

Comment: @MrYoshiji I am in a view where I render this partial. I need to send the location of the current view, through js, as value for the update_path parameter

Comment: You can't really do that, JS is executed on the client side (browser) whereas the ruby code is executed on the server-side

Comment: Thanks, forgot this basic rule.. I guess I can probably create a hidden field in partial, and then update it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you **need** to use JavaScript for this? If not, you can access the current full URL directly through Rails:

```
render "abc", :update_path => request.original_url
```

`request.original_url` would give you something similar to `http://mysite.com/my_controller/my_action?my_params=...` (i.e. it includes the **full** url, not just the part after the host/port). If you only need the path portion, you can do `request.fullpath` which would give you `/my_controller/my_action?my_params=...`.

See [How do I get the current absolute URL in Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165665/how-do-i-get-the-current-url-in-ruby-on-rails) for more info.