# A way to get full path + id [Rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am looking for a way to retrieve the URL path of a page, specifically, the full path to my blog post.

I would be looking for a way to retrieve this entire URL: `http://example.com/posts/1`

I am able to get this far: http://example.com/posts, however, I cannot find a way to dynamically pickup the id (1) at the end.

How should I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165665/how-do-i-get-the-current-url-in-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 0):

Try using `request.original_url`

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-original_url

Edit:

routes.rb

```
Stovf::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts
end
```

posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ActionController::Base
  def show
    # This is actually not needed for the example to work.
  end
end
```

posts/show.html.erb

```
<%= request.original_url %>
```

And the result is:
[image]