# Rspec and reset_session do not work together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, rspec

I am having some troubles with one rspec test. I am writing simple logging-in system. Everything works fine, except for the logging-out test:

```
context 'when user is logged in' do
  before(:each) do
    session[:user_id] = User.first.id;
  end

  it 'allows user to log out' do
    delete :destroy
    session.should be_empty
  end
end
```

Destroy action:

```
def destroy   
  reset_session
  redirect_to new_session_path
end
```

I have checked that during the test session is cleared right after `reset_session` command, however it is not cleared in rspec after `delete :destroy`. I am wondering how those two sessions are correlated.

I have also tried `session.delete(:user_id)` with exactly same result. It seems that rspec detects adding keys to session without any problems, but cannot see sth was removed. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my tests, `reset_session` does clear the `session` variable as perceived by RSpec based on tests before and after the `delete :destroy` call. I did have to remove a `notice:` on a following `redirect` in my controller, however, which otherwise populated the `session` variable with the notice information.

If you haven't already printed out the value of `session` within the controller before and after your redirect, I would do that.

Comment: Awesome, I would never think that redirect_to is setting anything in a session, but it makes perfect sense. In my case the problem was turbolinks (and fact that I cached current_user in a controller). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this test:

```
it 'allows user to log out' do
  delete :destroy
  request.original_url.eq new_session_path
end
```

This link may help you, [get current url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165665/how-do-i-get-the-current-url-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: Thx, I got NameErrorundefined local variable or method `current_url'. Apart of that it is avoiding the problem, not solving it.