# Ruby on Rails how to get current URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cross-domain

I'm trying to get the current URL in Rails using `request.host`, `request.url` but I have a website that is in 2 domains, so:

When I'm at `www.example1.com` the `request.host` or .url show `www.example1.com`

When I'm  at `www.example2.com` the `request.host` or .url shows `example1.com`
because the example2 is getting all content from example1 and showing it in the example2(parsed)

So the request.host gives me the host, and request.url seems to be giving me the host also
What I need is the URL that appears in the browser and not the host, any ideas?

Notes:

- I'm using Rails 4 and Ruby 2
- request.domain doesn't work, this returns just the ".com" piece of the URL

Comment: did you tried `request.original_url`?

Comment: @Lain Your effort to capitalize "i" in a whole lot of questions is appreciated, but try to make edits _substantial_. More often than not other things need fixing, too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the current absolute URL in Ruby on Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165665/how-do-i-get-the-current-absolute-url-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: http://blog.grepruby.com/2015/04/absolute-url-full-url-in-rails-4.html

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
request.original_url
```

shall provide you current url in rails 4.

You can visit this resource for more info @ [How do I get the current absolute URL in Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165665/how-do-i-get-the-current-absolute-url-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: this method don't works to me, i think this need to be something cross domain

Comment: puts your request object and see which object attribute is providing example2.com as value, you might get some idea for solution.

Answer (score 2):

For Rails 4 you should use request.original_url to get the current URL. More [detail](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-original_url).