# Changing Navbar Elements Depending On the Page Using an If Statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way to use an if statement to manipulate elements in a navbar based on what page you are on?

For example, what I'm trying to do is that I made my navbar on my homescreen transparent and the link texts are black. If I hover over a navbar link, the link text becomes white with a black background (this is what my class nav-font accomplishes). See below screenshot:

[image]
However, I want this color scheme to be inverted (or opposite) for all other pages that aren't the home page. Is this currently possible with Rails?

So I want to do the following in my layout file (application.html.erb) using the following pseudocode:

```
<% if we're on the homepage %>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right nav-font">
        <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Contact", new_contact_path %></li>
    </ul>
<% else %>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right nav-font-inverted">
        <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Contact", new_contact_path %></li>
    </ul>        
<% end %>
```

What I want to know is:

1. Is this possible? If so, how might I go about accomplishing this?
2. If not, is there a simpler solution or alternative?

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21430151/ruby-on-rails-how-to-get-current-url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
<% if controller_name == "your controller" && action_name = "your method" %>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right nav-font">
        <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Contact", new_contact_path %></li>
    </ul>
<% else %>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right nav-font-inverted">
        <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Contact", new_contact_path %></li>
    </ul>        
<% end %>
```

Comment: Ok, so my controller is named "PagesController" and it looks like this: https://puu.sh/ozurk/4f81e9c6ef.png      So what you are saying is that "controller_name" would be "PagesController" and the "action_name" would be "get?" If that's the case, how would that point to my homepage?

Comment: no the **action_name** will be the `def` you are calling on your controller

Comment: for example, `action_name == "index"`

Comment: and your **controller_name** should be `pages`

Comment: Thank you! I actually adjusted your code a little to "<% if controller_name === "pages" && action_name === "homepage" %>" so it works perfectly now.

Comment: Good to hear it helped you