# How to get application context in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

I have a URL like `http://myapp.myorg.com/MyApp/one/two` and I want to extract the first part myapp.myorg.com/MyApp/ in the Rails code. Please help me in getting this URL correct.

I'm currently using $servlet_context for this purpose, but it does not give me the result.

My code snippet:

`<%= link_to "My Link", "{@hostname}/#{$servlet_context}/three/four" %>`.

This gives me a URL like:

```
myapp/org.jruby.rack.servlet.ServletRackContext@622209db/three/four
```

I'm expecting something like:

```
myapp/MyApp/three/four
```

Comment: Why are you creating global variables inside a Rails application? That's a **super bad** idea.

Comment: Are you sure you want `myapp/MyApp/three/four`? Or did you mean to say  `myapp.myorg.com/MyApp/three/four`? Or say `MyApp/three/four`?

Comment: @KirtiThorat, both are fine, the server will resolve to myapp.myorg.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably get this by extracting the first part of [your path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165665/how-do-i-get-the-current-absolute-url-in-ruby-on-rails) by defining this in your controller:

```
def context_path(url)
  URI.join('/' + request.fullpath.split('/')[1], url)
end
helper_method :context_path
```

Then that's easy to incorporate into your URL:

```
<%= link_to "My Link", context_path('three/four') %>
```

Comment: when I added this method in the controller, I get the error, method not found. Instead if add this in the model, then I can call this method in the name create_context_path(url). When I execute this code, it gives the error "request" not found. Also it expects create_context_path.erb file. Please help me.

Comment: This is controller code that's also accessible in the view. You can't put it in a model, and in general models are not supposed to know anything about controllers. It breaks the concerns.

Comment: I have a helper file , I can put this function there. Its accessible from the partial. But there request is coming as nil. Any clues like whether I need to declare a request object in the controller?

Comment: If you're using this in the controller or view then `request` will be defined. Inside a model that doesn't make any sense and won't work.