# Rails 4 - How do I show a different view for the same controller action, based on the current route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a standard posts controller with an index action.

At the moment, I am routing this as the home page `/`, as well as the posts page `/posts`

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

    def index
    # Logic and finds here
    end

end
```

And in my `routes.rb` file:

```
root to: "posts#index"
get "/posts" => "posts#index"
```

However, in my view, I would like to lay things out slightly differently depending on whether the route is `/posts` or just `/`. Is this possible? And if so, what is the best practice for this?

I was thinking about creating another action in the posts controller, but then I would be replicating the logic, already defined in my index action - which I want to avoid.

I basically want to use the same content, but show a different view.

Any advice or help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Michael.

Comment: While it's possible, I think it would be more readable etc. if you use separate actions for these routes. You can put your logic from `index` action in separate private method in controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution apart from using different controllers/actions would be to pass an additional parameter in from your router:

```
root to: "posts#index", source: 'home'
get "/posts" => "posts#index"
```

Then in your controller you can do this:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # Logic
    render(params[:source] || 'index')
  end
end
```

It will render the `home` template when the user entered through the root path, and the `index` template otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

For the current scenario you can use this

In your action use

```
request.fullpath
```

This will catch the current uri, you can use this to implement things or in rails 4 you can also use

```
request.original_url
```

to fetch the URL, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165665/how-do-i-get-the-current-absolute-url-in-ruby-on-rails) question explains the use in details

Comment: `current_page?` method not available in action.