# How to fetch users browsing location and store in cookie in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cookies, setcookie

i want to store user selected location as cookie.
if location is not selected automatically it should fetch users browsing location and store as a cookie value. 
How to  do so?

i have done the code like this
when user selects a location, location is storing as cookie now by this code.

`@location = Location.find(location).name if location.present?
  cookies[:location_id] = { :value => @location, :expires => Time.now + 3600}`

But i don't have any idea to fetch users browsing location automatically and store in cookie.

Please help me to do this.

Any help is appreciatable.

Answer (score 0):

I have referred to the following for **retrieving current url**:

[How do I get the current absolute URL in Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165665/how-do-i-get-the-current-absolute-url-in-ruby-on-rails)

For references on how to store cookie, the references can be found from the following:

***(Do note the differences in different type of cookies that you can set, as you might want to set a cookie that expires on browser close or cookie that do not expires)***

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html

Combining both of these, I can write the code as follows:

**Storing cookie**:

```
cookies[:url] = request.original_url
```

**Retrieving stored cookie**:

```
url = cookies[:url]
```

Hope this helps.

Do let me know if I didn't answer your question correctly or you have any other questions.